# What do color enum "inherit" and "default" mean in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

A component's color in Material UI can be 
 'default' |
 'inherit' |
 'primary' |
 'secondary'

What do "default" and "inherit" mean here?   Some components' default color is "default", while some's is "inherit". This confuses me more.

I did a lot of search.  Can't find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some [materialUI docs](https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/#css-api) that describe it (albiet poorly, not specifically defining what inherit does)

I was not able to specifically find docs describing the behavior, however - all it does is set the color via css inherit, rather than explicitly defining the color. Which is to say, if the component is nested and you defined a specific color on the top level component, inherit will have the sub-component take that color, rather than being the default color.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is Inherit means the color of the text will be the same as the color of the text in the parent element

For example, if a parent component has a textColor of primary and a child component has a textColor of inherit, the child component's text will have the same color as the parent component's text that is defined as primary.